# Where to find 16.04 with the GA kernel

Tags: 16.04

I want the iso for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04  Not 16.04.2  I want the 4.4 kernel not the 4.8 HWE kernel but I can't find any iso for the original 16.04 release.

Can anyone show me a link?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... I found it here:  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/